# HTML 5 local storage between app and browser

Tags: android, ios, html, local-storage

Is it possible to access the same local storage from a mobile app (ios/android) and a website? For eg, test.com stores value A in local storage and then would the mobile app be able to access this value?

Comment: Do you mean that `test.com` is run in the stock browser, and stores some data using html5 local-storage API and then later `test.com` is loaded inside of it's own "wrapper" application (not the stock browser), would the instance in the wrapper application have access to the same data that was stored from the browser earlier?

Comment: chrome offer such kind function http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html but not HTML5.

Comment: @Patrick just tested this out, see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 local storage API does not dictate the internal storage format. Therefore it will lead to ad-hoc code to use the internal storage format. Portability across browsers can be a problem because of lack of internal format specification. If your mobile app (native app) writes something to the local storage you should ensure the format is 100% compliant with the browser's internal storage format because you don't want the browser to be confused with the data when the browser has to read it. There can be surprises when both the browser app and the mobile app are running because both of them can update the data. Who wins if there are conflicting updates? How do you ensure data writes do not end up in garbled file in case both browser and mobile app happen to write data at the same time? How do you protect against such race conditions? At least HTML5 has no locking mechanism! Looking at all this complexity I believe it is not worth the complexity and the pain!!

Comment: Doesn't matter the storage format, as long as both the native app and the browser can access the same storage value.

Comment: @Patrick Storage format definitely matters. When we have to store some value from HTML5 app we use the JS API. When I give a javascript integer to it I have no idea how it will store it on the disk - big endian, little endian, some kind of serialized object, some other binary format - I have absolutely no idea. Mobile app cannot read and use that value unless it knows in what format the value has been stored. For the mobile app to store a value and the HTMl5 app to read it, mobile app should stick to the HTML5 disk storage format. Therefore storage format is very important for the dual use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your standalone web app will have access to the same data that you stored from the browser.

At least in the case of standalone app this data is stored in an sqlite3 db that is inside that applications internal storage folder so something like `/data/data/com.your.package/databases/webdata.db` I forget the precise name, but it's in a db there somewhere.

The browser I would assume does something similar but stores it inside of it's own storage area `/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/`. I don't think the browser or stand alone apps would take the time to go through all of the db's for every possible application on the phone to find the data. (if it even could, I think those files are actually private to the specific application on a stock device)

**EDIT:** The results are in.

No your app cannot access the key/value pairs that were stored from the stock browser (or any other browser for that matter). Nor vice versa, no other browser can access the data that your stand alone app stored.

Comment: Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304102/migrating-local-storage-from-cordova-app-to-android-app ?