# Migrating local storage from Cordova app to Android App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

We have an application in Playstore which is developed using Cordova.
Now we have rebuilt the total app in Native Android.

Now we want to upgrade the user from the previous app to the new app without logout.

For that, how to migrate local data of Cordova(window.localStorage) to Android shared preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have migrated local data as follows

> 1. In Activity/Fragment view add webView and

```
        final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSetting = webView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //set callback to get data from webview to Native
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "MyHandler");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        //Create HTML file to read stored data in webView local storage and pass it to Native
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/readData.html");
```

> 2. Create Class `MyJavaScriptInterface` to communicate between webView and native as follows

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void sendKeyValue(String key, String value) {
            Log.d("sendKeyValue", "key:" + key + " value:" + value);
        }
     }
```

> 3. In assets folder add following readData.html file
>
>    ```
>     <html>
>     <body>
>     <div id="result"></div>
>     <div id="resultCount"></div>
>     <script>
>              // Check browser support
>              if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
>
>              for(i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
>                 console.log("key "+i+" "+localStorage.key(i));
>                 console.log("value"+i+" "+localStorage.key(i)+"= "+localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
>                 window.MyHandler.sendKeyValue(localStorage.key(i), localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
>                 }
>              }
>
>           </script>
>     </body>
>     </html>
>    ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [cordova-plugin-nativestorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage).

It allows a simple yet native persistant method to save data in Android and iOS by natively implementing SharedPreferences in Android and NSDefault in iOS.

**JavaScript:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage

NativeStorage.setItem("username","kalidoss",setSuccess, setError);
            function setSuccess(obj) {
               alert(obj);
            }
            function setError(error) {
               alert(error.code);
            }
```

**Java:**

```
Context context =this;
String MyPREFERENCES = "NativeStorage";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name= sharedpreferences.getString("username","");
```

Comment: This works only if we use NativeStorage in Cordova.
But in my case NativeStorage not used. In my case window.localStorage used in Cordova app